# How to fill only a part of the shape on CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, swift5, cashapelayer

I am creating following shape with UIBezierPath and then draw it with CAShapeLayer as following.

[image]

Then I can change CAShapeLayer fillColor property from `shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor` to `shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor` and get following shape.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var line = [CGPoint]()
    let bezierPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        let point1 = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        let point2 = CGPoint(x: 400, y: 100)

        line.append(point1)
        line.append(point2)

        addCircle(toRight: false)
        addLine()
        addCircle(toRight: true)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

         self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    func addLine() -> Void {
        bezierPath.move(to: line.first!)
        bezierPath.addLine(to: line.last!)
    }

    func addCircle(toRight: Bool) -> Void {
        let angle = CGFloat( Double.pi / 180 )
        let r = CGFloat(20.0)
        let x0 = toRight ? line.first!.x : line.last!.x
        let y0 = toRight ? line.first!.y : line.last!.y
        let x1 =  toRight ? line.last!.x : line.first!.x
        let y1 = toRight ? line.last!.y : line.first!.y
        let x = x1 - x0
        let y = y1 - y0
        let h = (x*x + y*y).squareRoot()
        let x2 = x0 + (x * (h + r) / h)
        let y2 = y0 + (y * (h + r) / h)

        // Add the arc, starting at that same point
        let point2 = CGPoint(x: x2, y: y2)
        let pointZeroDeg = CGPoint(x: x2 + r, y: y2)
        self.bezierPath.move(to: pointZeroDeg)
        self.bezierPath.addArc(withCenter: point2, radius: r,
                          startAngle: 0*angle, endAngle: 360*angle,
                          clockwise: true)
        self.bezierPath.close()
    }
}
```

But what I actually want is following shape (left side circle is filled, right side circle is not filled).

[image]

So my question is, **How to fill only a part of the shape on CAShapeLayer?**
Is it possible? Is there any trick to achieve this?

**PS:** I can achieve this by creating 3 different UIBezierPaths (for leftCircle, line and rightCircle) and drawing them with 3 different CAShapeLayers as following.

```
// left Circle
shapeLayer1.path = bezierPath1.cgPath
shapeLayer1.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

// line
shapeLayer2.path = bezierPath2.cgPath

// right Circle
shapeLayer3.path = bezierPath3.cgPath
shapeLayer3.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer1)
self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer2)
self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer3)
```

But I prefer to achieve this with a single CAShapeLayer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think better approach is using of multiple shapes.

However you can make one-shape implementation by using `evenOdd` rule of shape filling.

Just add an extra circle to the right circle in method `addCircle`:

```
if toRight {
    self.bezierPath.addArc(withCenter: point2, radius: r,
                      startAngle: 0*angle, endAngle: 2*360*angle,
                      clockwise: true)
} else {
    self.bezierPath.addArc(withCenter: point2, radius: r,
                      startAngle: 0*angle, endAngle: 360*angle,
                      clockwise: true)
}
```

And set `fillRule` to `evenOdd`:

```
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor        
shapeLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
```

So you'll get that the left circle will have one circle of drawing and will be filled by `evenOdd` rule. But right circle will have two circles of drawing and will be unfilled.

The `evenOdd` rule (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cashapelayerfillrule/1521843-evenodd):

> Specifies the even-odd winding rule. Count the total number of path
>   crossings. If the number of crossings is even, the point is outside
>   the path. If the number of crossings is odd, the point is inside the
>   path and the region containing it should be filled.